# Nodejs max number of open websocket on the server

Tags: node.js, performance, websocket, connection, max

I am finally trying to benchmark my nodejs application. To benchmark I open a nodejs instance where I run my server, and one where I run my benchmark.

The benchmark open a number of websockets, the server wait for all of them to be open, gets the data from them, and only after having all the data, crunch some numbers.

I have tested it with 2000 websocket and it works fine, then I have tried with 10 000 and it took 38 minutes to open all the connection.

Being my first nodejs/websocket project,I was wondering if that is a reasonable timing (I guess so), or 38 minutes means that something went wrong in my implementation?

**SHORT VERSION:** is 38 minutes "too long" to open 10 000 websockets on a nodejs server?

I am testing on a server with two AMD Opteron(TM) Processor 6272, with 96GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns) (12 x 8GB Memory Modules), but I am not doing any load balancing, i.e. my server (I think) runs on only one core.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by crunching numbers? NodeJS only uses a single thread -- trying to run a processor intensive logic in one request will block **all** other requests. (This effectively negates all the benefits of NodeJS because in effect, NodeJS serves the request of 10000 websockets one at a time)

Comment: But the "crunching part" doesn't happen until: I open the 10k websockets AND they send a single piece of data. It takes 38 minutes only to open the websockets and to send the (small) data (without the crunching). Only after that I do something with the data I have received (and that take about a minute).

Comment: 38 minutes is kinda long for 10k connections. However, according to http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+Opteron+6272, your server has 8 cores. You can try node-cluster (http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) to speed up your server up to 8x. It's actually pretty simple.

Comment: 38 minutes for 10k WS connections is totally slow. AutobahnPython on PyPy can do 14k full WebSocket opening+closing handshakes _per second_ on 4 cores. https://github.com/oberstet/wsperf_results/blob/master/handshaking/test2/results.pdf?raw=true And it easily does 200k concurrent connections on 1 core.

Comment: In other words: fast = 1 sec for opening 10k WebSocket connections.

Comment: How are you testing it ? locally - both server and client on same machine or remotely. @oberstet I dont the benchmark is 1 to 1 for the given scenario, it requires more than open and close handshake.

Comment: I am actually testing it remotely. I open two ssh connection: in one I run the benchmark, and in the other the server.

Comment: Locally or remotely makes no difference for _throughput_ (total handshakes/sec), only for latency. That is, given your load client can issues enough WebSocket connections _in parallel_. Use `wsperf` for that.